# MATLAB, subfunctions and an unknown variable

Tags: matlab

Basically, I'm trying to plot the error of two functions against an array [1,40] using `fplot`.

The error function is obvious : `E = (V2-V1)/V2`
Therefore I will use `fplot(E,1,40)`

However, the issue is that the function is defined in terms of `P` and not `V`, and I can't algebraically solve the equation for `V`

Formulas:

> P1 = (R*T)/(V-b) - x1/(V*(V+b))
>
> P2 = (R*T)/(V-b) - x2/(V*(V+b))

where `x1` and `x2` are specific to each equation and all other constants have been defined.

Can I use the `solve()` function, or `fzero` with a for loop in order the find the values of `V` as `P` varies from 1 to 40?

I am also confused as to how the `fplot` function works when defining multiple `subfunctions` under one main function.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, both equations are implicit in V. If you want to plot their error when varying P, I suggest you to write them in polynomial form (this are Van der Waals equations of state, right?).

For example, you can do this:

```
syms RT V b x1 x2 P1 P2
f = (RT)/(V-b) - x1/(V*(V+b))-P1
sol=solve(f,V)
```

And it will give you

```
sol =
 root(P1*z^3 - RT*z^2 - P1*b^2*z - RT*b*z + x1*z - b*x1, z, 1)
 root(P1*z^3 - RT*z^2 - P1*b^2*z - RT*b*z + x1*z - b*x1, z, 2)
 root(P1*z^3 - RT*z^2 - P1*b^2*z - RT*b*z + x1*z - b*x1, z, 3)
```

By solving this polynomial (for example, using the function `polysolve`) and choosing the right root, you can get the value of V for every P, then you can calculate E and plot the result for the array.